# Call Static Method in expression.call with arguments

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, expression-trees

I have extended the string class for `Contains` method. I'm trying to call it in `Expression.Call`, but how to pass the argument properly?

Code: String Contains method:

```
public static class StringExts
{
    public static bool NewContains(this string source, string ValToCheck, StringComparison StrComp)
    {
        return source.IndexOf(ValToCheck, StrComp) >= 0;
    }
}
```

In Expression calling as :

```
public class Person { public string Name {get; set;} }

public class Persons { 
    public List<Person> lstPersons {get; set;} 
    public Persons() {
      lstPersons = new List<Person>();    
    }
}

public class Filter 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public void Main()
{
   //Get the json.
   //"Filters": [{"id": "Name", "operator": "contains", "value": "Microsoft"}]

    Filter Rules = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Filter>(json);

   // Get the list of person firstname.
    List<Person> lstPerson = GetFirstName();

   ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "p");
   Expression exp = null;

   exp = GetExpression(param, rules[0]);

   //get all the name contains "john" or "John"
   var filteredCollection = lstPerson.Where(exp).ToList();

}

private Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression param, Filter filter){
   MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, filter.Id);
   ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(filter.value);

   Expression bEXP = null;

   switch (filter.Operator)
    {
         case Operator.contains:
           MethodInfo miContain = typeof(StringExts).GetMethod("NewContains", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
           return  Expression.Call(miContain, member, constant , Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));; 
           break;
    }
 }
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll.Additional information: Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.

How to call the parameter in `miContain` for following `Call()` methods?

I have updated the Code.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but are you aware there already is a [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: @Sayse There isn't one that takes StringComparison as an additional argument.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are not specifying all parameters. If you create expressions for all, it works:

```
ParameterExpression source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
string ValToCheck = "A";
StringComparison StrComp = StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

MethodInfo miContain = typeof(StringExts).GetMethod("NewContains", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var bEXP = Expression.Call(miContain, source, Expression.Constant(ValToCheck), Expression.Constant(StrComp));

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(bEXP, source);

bool b = lambda.Compile().Invoke("a");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm using Expression in Linq.Where(), can source be member such that. Expression.call(miContain, member, Expression.Constant(ValToCheck), Expression.Constant(StrComp)

Comment: Sure, pass in a `ParameterExpression`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Your answers also helped me to solve my problem. Also @PatrickHofman you can use the ".Where(expressionCompiled)" in a more generic way, read this blog post www.pashov.net/code/dynamic+filters

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified enough arguments (2 vs. 3). `NewContains` has three arguments.

Also, since this method is not an instance method you can't set the this parameter. [This overload looks better.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301084(v=vs.110).aspx)

You probably should have examined the [overload list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call(v=vs.110).aspx). That is how I found the right answer to this question without knowing it myself beforehand.